# ARM: How does VIC interact with flash vector table?

Tags: vector, arm, interrupt

I have problems getting an interrupt-driven LED flasher going on an ARM LPC2138.  If I change to polling the timer, it works fine, so the problem seems to be the interrupts. The program is essentially a copy of demo code off the web, adapted for my IDE.

I’m prepared to keep trying things and failing repeatedly because that’s how you learn, but I would appreciate one specific clarification regarding how the VIC works, so I can eliminate one potential cause.

There’s an interrupt vector table in flash, starting at location 0x0. A MEMMAP register allows it to be mapped to the bottom of RAM, 0x4000000. However, there is also  code in setting up the VIC, as follows:

VICVectCntl4 = 0x20 | 4 ;     // 4 informs VIC which address register to use.

VICVectAddr4 = (unsigned) timerISR;  // ISR address

VICIntEnable |= 0x10 ;  // Enable tmr0 interrupt.

My code also contains the ISR function timerISR(), of course.

This suggests that the timer vector in the tables is not used, since the address of the (my) ISR is specified in the VIC vector address register.

Q:  Is there any interaction at all between my program and the flash/remapped timer vector address, or is it ignored in this case? If it is involved, how does this occur?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a look at page 13 of the datasheet for the LPC2138,
 (http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10120.pdf) it seems that the interrupts mapped at the beginning of flash (or RAM, if the bit you mentioned is set) are the core processor exception handlers. These interrupts are standard across all ARM7 processors. If you look at the particular interrupts that are made available there, you'll notice that there's nothing specific to a particular timer or peripheral.

The "VIC" peripheral on the chip is designed to easily handle miscellaneous interrupt sources, such as timers or external pin wakeups. It provides an additional facility for tying a particular interrupt directly to a function in code, which is what the snippet you call out seems to be configuring.

There's a dedicated reference manual for the VIC on the LPC2138 which can be found here: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0181e/DDI0181.pdf . Section 2.2 Operation provides good information on how this operates.